# In-App Purchase Auto-Renewable Subscription error code 21005

Tags: in-app, auto-renewing

One of my customer is getting error code 21005, tough he has a valid subscription..
As per apple docs, it is given "The receipt server is not currently available." for 21005.
Anybody knows what does exactly the error means.

Answer (score 0):

we got them too about 36 hours ago.  I think it means what it said, some of the servers had downtime.